# Print bottom view of a binary tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, binary-tree

For a binary tree we define horizontal distance as follows:

```
    Horizontal distance(hd) of root = 0
    If you go left then hd = hd(of its parent)-1, and 
    if you go right then hd = hd(of its parent)+1.
```

The bottom view of a tree then consists of all the nodes of the tree, where there is no node with the same `hd` and a greater level. (There may be multiple such nodes for a given value of `hd`. In this case all of them belong to the bottom view.) I'm looking for an algorithm that outputs the bottom view of a tree.

---

Examples:

Suppose the binary tree is:

```
         1
        /  \
       2    3
      / \  / \
     4   5 6  7
            \
             8
```

Bottom view of the tree is: 4 2 5 6 8 7

```
    Ok so for the first example,
    Horizontal distance of node with value 1: 0, level = 1
    Horizontal distance of node with value 2: 0 - 1 = -1, level = 2
    Horizontal distance of node with value 3: 0 + 1 = 1, level = 2
    Horizontal distance of node with value 4: -1 - 1 = -2, level = 3
    Horizontal distance of node with value 5: -1 + 1 = 0, level = 3
    Horizontal distance of node with value 6: 1 - 1 = 0, level = 3
    Horizontal distance of node with value 7: 1 + 1 = 2, level = 3
    Horizontal distance of node with value 8: 0 + 1 = 1, level = 4

    So for each vertical line that is for hd=0, print those nodes which appear in the last level of that line.
    So for hd = -2, print 4
    for hd = -1, print 2
    for hd = 0, print 5 and 6 because they both appear in the last level of that vertical line
    for hd = 1, print 8
    for hd = 2, print 7
```

One more example for reference :

```
         1
      /     \
    2         3
   / \       / \
  4   5     6     7 
 / \ / \   / \    / \
8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

So the output for this will be :
8 4 9 10 12 5 6 11 13 14 7 15

```
Similarly for this example
hd of node with value 1: 0, , level = 1
hd of node with value 2: -1, level = 2
hd of node with value 3: 1, level = 2
hd of node with value 4: -2, level = 3
hd of node with value 5: 0, , level = 3
hd of node with value 6: 0, level = 3
hd of node with value 7: 2, level = 3
hd of node with value 8: -3, level = 4
hd of node with value 9: -1, level = 4
hd of node with value 10: -1, level = 4
hd of node with value 11: 1, level = 4
hd of node with value 12: -1, level = 4
hd of node with value 13: 1, level = 4
hd of node with value 14: 1, level = 4
hd of node with value 15: 3, level = 4

So, the output will be:
hd = -3, print 8
hd = -2, print 4
hd = -1, print 9 10 12
hd = 0, print 5 6
hd = 1, print 11 13 14
hd = 2, print 7
hd = 3, print 15 

So the ouput will be:
8 4 9 10 12 5 6 11 13 14 7 15
```

---

I already know a method in which I can do it using a lot of extra space (a map, and a 1-D array for storing the level of the last element in that vertical line) and with time complexity of $O(N \log N)$.
And this is the implementation of this method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Node{
       int data;
       struct Node *left, *right;
};

Node* newNode(int data)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}

int height(Node *node)
{
    if(node == NULL)
            return 0;
    else{
         int lh = height(node->left);
         int rh = height(node->right);

         if(lh > rh)
               return (lh+1);
         else
               return (rh+1);
    }
}

void printBottom(Node *node, int level, int hd, int min, map< int, vector<int> >& visited, int lev[], int l)
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;
     if(level == 1){
              if(lev[hd-min] == 0 || lev[hd-min] == l){
                      lev[hd-min] = l;
                      visited[hd-min].push_back(node->data);
              }
     }
     else if(level > 1)
     {
          printBottom(node->left, level-1, hd-1, min, visited, lev, l);
          printBottom(node->right, level-1, hd+1, min, visited, lev, l);
     }
}

void findMinMax(Node *node, int *min, int *max, int hd)
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;

     if(hd < *min)
          *min = hd;
     else if(hd > *max)
          *max = hd;

     findMinMax(node->left, min, max, hd-1);
     findMinMax(node->right, min, max, hd+1);
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = newNode(1);
    root->left = newNode(2);
    root->right = newNode(3);
    root->left->left = newNode(4);
    root->left->right = newNode(5);
    root->right->left = newNode(6);
    root->right->right = newNode(7);
    root->left->left->left = newNode(8);
    root->left->left->right = newNode(9);
    root->left->right->left = newNode(10);
    root->left->right->right = newNode(11);
    root->right->left->left = newNode(12);
    root->right->left->right = newNode(13);
    root->right->right->left = newNode(14);
    root->right->right->right = newNode(15);

    int min = 0, max = 0;

    findMinMax(root, &min, &max, 0);

    int lev[max-min+1];
    map < int, vector<int> > visited;
    map< int,vector<int> > :: iterator it;

    for(int i = 0; i < max-min+1; i++)
            lev[i] = 0;

    int h = height(root);

    for (int i=h; i>0; i--){
        printBottom(root, i, 0, min, visited, lev, i);
    }

    for(it = visited.begin() ; it != visited.end() ; it++) {
        for(int i=0 ; i < it->second.size() ; i++) {
            cout << it->second[i] << " ";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am seeking help to do this in more optimized way, which used less space or time. Is there any other efficient method for this problem?

Comment: Why would the last example's output not be `8 4 9 10 5 11 12 6 13 14 7 15`? Or does order not matter?

Comment: Order does matter. I have explained the examples now, hope it becomes clear with it.

Comment: May I know the reason for giving a down vote? The question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can get the time complexity down to O(n), while keeping the same space complexity. You can do this by filling `visited` in a single run of `printBottom`:

```
void printBottom(Node *node, int level, int hd, int min, map< int, vector<int> >& visited, int lev[])
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;
     if(lev[hd-min] < level){
         lev[hd-min] = level;
         visited[hd-min] = new vector<int>; //erase old values, they are hidden by the current node
     }
     if(lev[hd-min] <= level){
         visited[hd-min].push_back(node->data);
     }
     printBottom(node->left, level+1, hd-1, min, visited, lev);
     printBottom(node->right, level+1, hd+1, min, visited, lev);
}
```

with the initial call `printBottom(root, 1, 0, min, visited, lev);`

If you insist on the nodes beig output in order of increasing value of `hd`, I don't think you can improve space consumption. However, if you allow a different order of output, you can get rid of `visited`, by first determining for each value of 'hd', which level should be output and then making another pass, printing the values that match:

```
void fillLev(Node *node, int level, int hd, int min, int lev[])
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;
     if(lev[hd-min] < level){
         lev[hd-min] = level;
     }
     fillLev(node->left, level+1, hd-1, min, lev);
     fillLev(node->right, level+1, hd+1, min, lev);
}
void printBottom(Node *node, int level, int hd, int min, int lev[])
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;
     if(lev[hd-min] == level){
         cout << node->data;
     }
     printBottom(node->left, level+1, hd-1, min, lev);
     printBottom(node->right, level+1, hd+1, min, lev);
}
```

with calls `fillLev(root, 1, 0, min, lev);` and `printBottom(root, 1, 0, min, lev);`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void bottomView(node *root)
{
    if(!root)
        return ;
    bottomView(root->left);
    if(!root->left || !root->right)
        cout<<"\t"<<root->data;
    if ((root->right && !root->right->left) && (root->left &&!root->left->right))
        cout<<"\t"<<root->data;
    bottomView(root->right);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution in java is given below,

Intiall call would be,

```
boolean obstructionFromLeftSide = printBottomViewOrderOfTree(root.left, true);
boolean obstructionFromRightSide = printBottomViewOrderOfTree(root.right, false);
if (!(obstructionFromLeftSide || obstructionFromRightSide))
    out.println(root.data + " ");
```

and function is given here,

```
    boolean printBottomViewOrderOfTree(Node root, boolean fromLeftSide)
   {
    if (root == null)
        return false;
    boolean obstructionFromLeftSide = printBottomViewOrderOfTree(root.left, true);
    boolean obstructionFromRightSide = printBottomViewOrderOfTree(root.right, false);
    if (!(obstructionFromLeftSide || obstructionFromRightSide))
        out.println(root.data + " ");
    if (fromLeftSide)
    {
        return root.right != null;
    }
    else
    {
        return root.left != null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using HashMap based on horizontal distance and level?
In C++, we can have a HashMap like this :

```
map<int,map<int,vector<int>>> HM;    
// Let Horizontal Distance = HD,Level = L  
// HM[HD][L] -> Vector tracking every node for a given HD,L
```

This approach has Time=O(n) and has improvement over your code on removing the clumsy fillLev() function. All we do here is single tree traversal and single hashmap traversal. Here's the code :

```
void getBottomView(struct node *tree,int HD,int L,map<int,map<int,vector<int>>> &HM)
{
    if(tree==NULL)
        return;

    HM[HD][L].push_back(tree->data);
    getBottomView(tree->left,HD-1,L+1,HM);
    getBottomView(tree->right,HD+1,L+1,HM);
}

void printBottomViewbyMap(map<int,map<int,vector<int>>> &HM)
{
    map<int,map<int,vector<int>>>::iterator i;

    for(i=HM.begin() ; i!=HM.end() ; i++)
    {
        if(i->second.size()==1)
        {
            map<int,vector<int>>::iterator mapi;
            mapi = i->second.begin();
            for(int j=0 ; j<= mapi->second.size()-1 ; j++)
                cout<<mapi->second[j]<<" ";
        }
        else
        {
            map<int,vector<int>>::reverse_iterator mapi;
            mapi = i->second.rbegin();
            for(int j=0 ; j<= mapi->second.size()-1 ; j++)
                cout<<mapi->second[j]<<" ";
        }
    }
} 

void printBottomView(struct node *tree)
{
    map<int,map<int,vector<int>>> HM;
    getBottomView(tree,0,0,HM);
    printBottomViewbyMap(HM);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the algorithm closely, you only reach nodes of higher horizontal levels incrementally. If we had an array (we can't because of negative horizontal distances), we would just need to do A[horizontalDistance] = node.

Then traverse this array to print the bottom view.

This would work because the array will store the bottom most element for a particular horizontal distance because we are doing a level order traversal.

Now then to solve the negative index problem, create a class called BiDirectionalList. In java you can use two ArrayLists or in C++ you can use two std::vectors.

I have posted the code here: http://tech.prakyg.com/2017/07/14/printing-bottom-view-of-binary-tree-in-on-time-without-using-a-map/

But here is the BiDirectionalList that you will need to code:

```
public class BiDirectionalList<T> {
List<T> forward;
List<T> reverse;

public BiDirectionalList() {
    forward = new ArrayList<>();
    reverse = new ArrayList<>();
    reverse.add(null); //0 index of reverse list will never be used
}

public int size() {
    return forward.size() + reverse.size()-1;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    if (forward.isEmpty() && reverse.size() == 1) return true;
    return false;
}

public T get(int index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        reverse.get(-index);
    } 
    return forward.get(index);
}

/**
 * Sets an element at given index only if the index <= size.
 * i.e. either overwrites an existing element or increases the size by 1
 * @param index 
 * @param element
 */
public void set(int index, T element) {
    if (index < 0) {
        index = -index;
        if (index  > reverse.size()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index can at max be equal to size");
        else if (reverse.size() == index ) reverse.add(index, element);
        else reverse.set(index, element);

    } else {
        if (index > forward.size()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index can at max be equal to size");
        else if (forward.size() == index ) forward.add(index, element);
        else forward.set(index, element);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here we have to keep the record of level of tree and horizontal distance from root node.

```
 void printBottom(Node *root,int dif,int level,map<int, pair<int,int> > &map){
    if(root==NULL)return;
    if(map.find(dif)==map.end() || level>= map[dif].second){
        map[dif] = {root->data,level};
    }
    printBottom(root->left,dif-1,level+1,map);
    printBottom(root->right,dif+1,level+1,map);
}

void bottomView(Node *root){
       map<int ,pair<int,int> > map;
       printBottom(root,0,0,map);
       for(auto it : map){
           printf("%d ",it.second.first);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

c# Implementation :

```
        public class node
        {
            public int data;
            public node left, right;
            public int hd;
        }

        static node newNode(int item)
        {
            node temp = new node();
            temp.data = item;
            temp.left = null;
            temp.right = null;
            return temp;
        }

        static void rightViewOfBT(node root)
        {
            Queue<node> queue = new Queue<node>();
            SortedDictionary<int, int> treeMap = new SortedDictionary<int, int>();
            int hd = 0;
            root.hd = hd;
            queue.Enqueue(root);
            while(queue.Count > 0)
            {
                node temp = queue.Peek();
                queue.Dequeue();

                if (treeMap.ContainsKey(temp.hd))
                {
                    treeMap[temp.hd] = temp.data;
                }
                else
                {
                    treeMap.Add(temp.hd, temp.data);
                }

                if (temp.left != null)
                {
                    temp.left.hd = temp.hd - 1;
                    queue.Enqueue(temp.left);
                }

                if (temp.right != null)
                {
                    temp.right.hd = temp.hd + 1;
                    queue.Enqueue(temp.right);
                }
            }
            foreach (var tree in treeMap)
                Console.Write(tree.Value);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            node root = newNode(1);
            root.left = newNode(2);
            root.right = newNode(3);
            root.left.left = newNode(4);
            root.left.right = newNode(5);
            root.left.left.right = newNode(8);
            root.left.right.left = newNode(9);
            root.right.left = newNode(6);
            root.right.right = newNode(7);
            root.right.right.right = newNode(11);
            root.right.left.right = newNode(10);
            rightViewOfBT(root);
        }
```